# Why does NSMutablearray keep returning null?

Tags: objective-c, methods, nsmutablearray, ddmathparser

I am generating a random equation say like 2*3+4..... and using DDMathparser to evaluate it. Here I have a class method which is supposed to return a random equation(stored inside a mutable array) only if it evaluates to a integer. 
however it keeps returning Null and i can't figure out why. Please help me out.!

```
#import "Equation.h"
#import "DDMathParser.h"

@implementation Equation
-(NSMutableArray*)randEquation{
    NSMutableArray* usableEquation=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    while(1){
    NSArray *nums = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9"];
    unsigned index1=arc4random()%9;
    NSString* num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [nums objectAtIndex:index1]];
    NSArray *symbols = @[@"+", @"-", @"*", @"/"];
    unsigned index=arc4random()%4;
    NSString* symb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [symbols objectAtIndex:index]];
        NSMutableArray *arrayOfSymbolsAndNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for( int i=0;i<=10;i++){
            if (i%2==0) {
                [arrayOfSymbolsAndNumbers addObject:num];
            }
            else{
                [arrayOfSymbolsAndNumbers addObject:symb];
            }

        }
        NSMutableString *stringOfSymbolsAndNumbers=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        for (NSObject * obj in arrayOfSymbolsAndNumbers)
        {
            [stringOfSymbolsAndNumbers appendString:[obj description]];


        }
        usableEquation=arrayOfSymbolsAndNumbers;
        NSNumber *result=[stringOfSymbolsAndNumbers numberByEvaluatingString];
        float resultFloat = [result floatValue];
        float checker=resultFloat;
        if (floor(checker)==checker) {
            break;
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    return usableEquation;
}

@end
```

Comment: How are you checking the `nil` return? What debugging have you done?

Comment: In the story board i tried NSlog with the returned array by using
    NSLog(@"The content of array is%@",[equation randEquation]);
and the output on my console is  :The content of array is(null).

Also I am setting the titles of some buttons to the content of that array and the titles are not being set.

Comment: In the previous comment in:  NSLog(@"The content of array is%@",[equation randEquation]); "equation is just an instance of my class "Equation".

Comment: Learn how to debug.  Start at the point of the exception, figure out which value is nil, and work backwards to where that value is generated.

Answer (score 0):

> NSLog(@"The content of array is%@",[equation randEquation]);

Based on your code, for this log to output `The content of array is(null)` means that `equation` is nil. Your `randEquation` (while not efficient) looks ok, the problem is that you haven't created the `equation` instance when you run the log statement.